# How to set a variable to a query? mongodb

Tags: node.js, function, mongodb, mongoose

How do I set a variable to a query? I am trying to use functions and callbacks in node.js to work through async, but I am not sure how to get a query to equal to a variable. What I am trying to do in this code is take a friend collection that belongs to a user and return the friends result(which I don't think I am doing correctly in the query insertAll) and then find the user's info for each of the query. And then return the results as a render. I am not sure how to call render either with this...

Here is my code:

```
exports.contactList = function(req, res) {

    var insertFriend = function(data, callback) {
        var friend = User.findById({_id: user.friendStatus.fuId}, function() {
            callback(null, data);
        }, friend);
    };;

    var insertAll = function(coll, callback) {
        var queue = coll.slice(0),
        friendX;

        (function iterate(){
            if(queue.length === 0) {
                callback();
                return;
            }
            friendX = queue.splice(0,1)[0];
            insertFriend(friendX, function(err, friendX) {
                if(err) {throw err;}
                console.log(friendX + ' inserted');
                process.nextTick(iterate);

            });
        })();
    };



    insertAll([Friend.findOne({userId: req.signedCookies.userid})], function(){

    });

};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Query` object is returned if you do not pass a callback.

From http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html:

> When a callback function:
>
> is passed, the operation will be executed immediately with the results passed to the 
>   callback.
>
> is not passed, an instance of Query is returned, which provides a special QueryBuilder 
>   interface for you.